# Can't add admin in Shield Elasticsearch - [Error]Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.shield.authc.esusers.tool.ESUsersTool

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-shield

I am trying out Shield as a security measure for my Kibana and Elasticsearch. Running on Mac OS X 10.9.5

Followed the documentation from [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/shield). Managed to install Shield. Since my Elasticsearch is running automatically, I skipped step 2(start elasticsearch).

For step 3, I tried adding an admin. Ran this following command on my terminal. `bin/shield/esusers useradd admin -p password -r admin`.

Unfortunately I'm getting this error.

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.shield.authc.esusers.tool.ESUsersTool

Below are the additional steps I took.

1. Double checked that the `bin/shield esusers` path existed and all.
2. Manually starting elasticsearch before adding users
3. Tried a variety of different commands based on the documentation.
   `bin/shield/esusers useradd admin -r admin` and
   `bin/shield/esusers useradd es_admin -r admin`
4. Ran those commands with sudo

Same error generated. Can't seem to find the problem on google as well. Not really sure what I'm missing here as the documentation seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Did you restart the nodes after install? Also, did you install on **all** nodes?

Comment: @AndreiStefan, I'm trying this on my local machine, so only one node. I did not restart my nodes, should I do that before I add a new user ??

Comment: You should restart the node because new Java classes were added to it and the JVM behind Elasticsearch needs to reload those classes. It can only do that if you restart it. That's the reasoning.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I can't seem to find it anywhere on how to restart the nodes. Mind pointing me to the right direction? Sorry, I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: Kill the process, start it up again :-). Or `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_shutdown"`

Comment: @AndreiStefan thank you. I think the problem was caused because of me not restarting my nodes. Not too sure though why now it's giving me an authentication error. Tried the username and password I used when adding the admin, not working.

Comment: @AndreiStefan if you add your solution as an answer, I'll accept it since it did solve my original question.

Comment: Done, but you can add another post with the details related to the username password not working, if you don't see a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *must* restart the node because new Java classes were added to it (from the Shield plugin) and the JVM behind Elasticsearch needs to reload those classes. It can only do that if you restart it.

Kill the process and start it up again, or use `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_shutdown"` to shut the cluster down.

Also, the Shield plugin needs to be installed on all the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: This was exactly what was missing. Noticed it in the documentation(long version) after reading your answer. Thanks !!