# Can't add an admin in elasticsearch Shield [Error]: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.shield.authc.esusers.tool.ESUsersTool

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-shield

Good Morning

I am trying since yesterday to add an admin account to the `elasticsearch 2.4` shield plugin. I am using `Ubuntu 14.04` on one node and `Ubuntu 16.04` on the two other nodes.
I have installed the Shield plugin on my Logstash Server and there it worked. On my Elasticsearch Server I have installed the Java Version:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
```

I tried the command:

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/shield/esusers useradd esadm -r admin
```

I am always getting the error:

```
Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.shield.authc.esusers.tool.ESUsersTool
```

I installed the Shield Plugin on all three Nodes and restarted the elasticsearch service on all nodes and I also rebooted all three nodes :)

Anyone an Idea?

PS: I have done the steps of the question: [Can't add admin in Shield Elasticsearch - [Error]Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.shield.authc.esusers.tool.ESUsersTool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201794/cant-add-admin-in-shield-elasticsearch-errorcould-not-find-or-load-main-cla) and it's still not working.

Comment: I have found a solution for this problem. In the esuers script you have to set the `$CLASSPATH` to your own directory where you have installed your plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add `path.plugins` to your elasticsearch.yml? I have the same problem with you. And after I removed `path.plugins`, it works.

Comment: yes I had it but the esusers script is not taking the path.plugins from the elasticsearch.yml. After I added manual the path to the plugins in the esusers script it worked (like my comment to the questinon said :))

Comment: Right, that's why no class found. :)